# App Icons from MakeAppIcon didn't successfully appear

Tags: ios

I went to MakeAppIcon and made them. Posted over there and deleted an icon called "App-Icon-76x76@2x.png". But when I launched on my iPad, the icon didn't appear. By the way, the other app is successfully appearing icon so I think this is not the iPad problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The reason that I deleted "App-Icon-76x76@2x.png" is that there is shown yellow triangle.

Comment: My friend's app launched, showed the app and the icon. I did that in same, but only my app shown(neither my icon). I used 1024x1024 to create them, and I noticed my friend's icons in Assets.xcassets were IOS 5-12, is there any different? Or I can just ignore? (I don't update my Xcode so it max IOS 11.4, and my iPad is IOS 10.3.2).

Answer (score 0):

The icon 76x76@2x is used for Retina display on iPads, so if you delete it, you'll not see the icon.
So you need to create one from your original that makes 152px x 152px, it will normally avoid the yellow error.

Comment: You mean I need to make a 152x152@1x to replace the icon 76x76@2x?

Comment: No, you need to make an 152x152px icon, but named 76x76@2x